# ctrl+shift+t event in durandal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, durandal

i am working on a Microsoft .NET MVC Durandal application. I want to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> event. I used knockout keypress event.

When i click some parts of the screen like (header, footer), I am able to capture it, but if i click any where else in the view, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> , it doesn't capture the event ? I assume that durandal uses this event for its background something...

i tried having this event in the shell and the same thing happens. it does not detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> :(

but detects many others like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, on my main parent view (as i am using Durandal), i use a JQuery keyup event and it detects my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> thing :)